# phonegap nagivation.notification is underfined for wp8

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, phonegap-plugins

I am new to Cordova and trying to learn it. Right now I am stuck with notifications. I can't really get them working. Can someone point out what is my problem?

Here is the JS code inside *main.js*

```
function init() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', deviceReady, false);
}

function deviceReady() {
    var LSsupport = !(typeof window.localStorage == 'undefined');
    var SSsupport = !(typeof window.sessionStorage == 'undefined');
    if (LSsupport && SSsupport) {
        try {
            console.log('bbb');
            if (navigator != null) {
                console.log(navigator);
                navigator.notification.beep(2);
            }
            else {
                alert('aaaa');
            }
        } catch (e) {
            alert("Beep failed: " + e.message);
        }
    }
    else {
        switchPages('#welcome', '#not_supported');
    }
}
```

Here is *index.html*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
<body onload="init();">

    <div data-role="page" id="welcome" class="page">
        <div data-role="content" class="content">
            Welcome To My First Phonegap Application
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova_plugins.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and finally *config.xml*

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.example" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
    <name>HelloWorld</name>
    <description>
        Hello World sample application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="support@phonegap.com" href="http://phonegap.com">
        PhoneGap Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <preference name="permissions" value="none" />
    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.5.0" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="default" />
    <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
    <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
    <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />
    <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
    <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
    <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7" />
    <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.battery-status" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration" />
    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="ldpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="mdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="hdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="blackberry" src="www/res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover" src="www/res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="57" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-57.png" width="57" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="72" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="114" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png" width="114" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="144" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png" width="144" />
    <icon gap:platform="webos" src="www/res/icon/webos/icon-64.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="winphone" src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="winphone" gap:role="background" src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173-tile.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="blackberry" src="www/res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="480" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" width="320" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="960" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" width="640" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="1136" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png" width="640" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="1024" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" width="768" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="768" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" width="1024" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="winphone" src="www/res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <feature name="Notification">
        <param name="wp-package" value="Notification" />
    </feature>
</widget>
```

When I list plugins on command line it shows the following

```html
C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\hello>phonegap plugins list
org.apache.cordova.dialogs 0.2.11 "Notification"
```

Also I am getting following output message.

```html
Adding feature.value=Notification
CordovaBrowser_LoadCompleted
Apache Cordova native platform version 3.7.0 is starting
deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.
Channel not fired: onPluginsReady
Channel not fired: onCordovaReady
```

Comment: Does the `phonegap plugins list` really only show the _dialogs_ plugin? Please show also the rest of those. I suppose some other plugin prevents the loading of _dialogs_ plugin. Also, have you tried running it on actual device instead of simulator since there the plugins should become ready.

Comment: hi sanfor. As i read, starting from phonegap 3 something, phonegap comes without plugins. so i installed only org.apache.cordova.dialogs

Comment: Yes, no plugins come automatically attached (they wouldn't be much of plugins if they did, would they). You just have the PhoneGap Build directives (`<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" />` etc.) on your _config.xml_ for using bunch of plugins, so that is why I was wondering why you don't have any others on CLI.

Comment: it all came out after executing 'phonegap platform add wp8'

Comment: ok, guys, it worked out. the problem was that i was adding plugin after adding the platform. it should be visa versa.